# Determine when Chrome Extension free trial is over

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, licensing

So I have a Chrome Extension that is set up for one-time payment with a free trial period.

I see this data right now when I login with the Chrome accounts API (`chrome.identity.getAuthToken`):

```
{
    accessLevel: "FREE_TRIAL"
    createdTime: "1515085366930"
    itemId: "omelijcoklxxokoeobkpepozpjpbakoeo"
    kind: "chromewebstore#userLicense"
    maxAgeSecs: "2"
    result: true
}
```

the above JSON is from the parsed response from this call:

```
   const url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/userlicenses/' + chrome.runtime.id;
   const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open('GET', url);
   req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
   req.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (req.readyState == 4) {
       const license = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
       self.license = license;
     }

   };

   req.send();
```

my question is - how do I know when the free trial period is over? It looks like I get to determine how long the free trial period is programmatically.

Is there a recommended way to control for the free trial period?

Do I just compared the createdTime to a Date.now() value and look at the elapsed time? What is a good way to display to the user that they are on the free trial and show how much time remains?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I know when the free trial period is over? Do I just compared the createdTime to a Date.now() value and look at the elapsed time?

yes. if `Date.now() - createdTime` is greater then the desired free trial period, it has expired.

> Is there a recommended way to control for the free trial period?

the documentation has some example code.
https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments#trial-limited-time

set `var TRIAL_PERIOD_DAYS` to how long you desire.
set `var license` to the json you got, and the documentation code should work as is.

> What is a good way to display to the user that they are on the free trial and show how much time remains?

the `var license` was set in the background script. you need to pass it to your content script. to do that, from the content script, you send a message to the background script using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`.
then, from the background script, you send an answer using `sendResponse(license)`.
now you got that variable in your content script. use it to check if the trial is still in effect then manipulate the dom, inserting warning messages and the remaining time.

please note, the user must be logged in to the chrome browser in order for the extension to be able to get the license. if he is not, you have to decide if you want to allow or deny the extension's functionality.